# Redirect the output of "ssh -T git@github.com"

Tags: bash, ssh

I am attempting to check the output of running the command 
"ssh -T git@github.com"

The output should look like:

> Hi xyz! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

However, I am unable to capture this output. Where is this text coming from and how can I access it so I can test against it?

Piping the output or writing to a file yields no results.

```
ssh -T git@github.com | grep "successful"
```

Grep here receives no input.

Comment: try `ssh -T git@github.com  2>&1| grep successful`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @shellter! And for other people arriving who will probably have the same next question as me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean

Comment: @shellter, can you add the same as an answer so that ampix can accept it. It will mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error messages are usually written to a separate "stream" called StdErr.

You can redirect the StdErr output to be merged with the StdOut (output).

```
git@github.com 2>&1 | grep "successful"
```

Will solve your problem.

```
2>&1 
|| |
|| +-> 1 is the filehandle num assosciated with stdin
|+---> >& redirects from left to right, "merging" the 2 specified streams 
+===-> 2 is the filehandle number for stderr
```

Comment: @Ampix0 : See my full answer to your Q about `ssh` ;-).

Comment: @Mihir : Per your request. `ssh` comment turned into an answer ;-)